# how do we find the x,y from and to values for the drag method of com.robotium.solo.Solo?

Tags: android, robotium

how do we find the x,y from, and to for use with com.robotium.solo.Solo.drag.(float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY, int stepCount)?  Is there some type of IDE or some way to activate some feature of the emulator that can display the x,y values?

where is the origin: x,y, top left corner? bottom corner?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch uiautomatorviewer from directory tool of your sdk. Then you have to click on the second icon in the top left of this screen and you get the layout of the application under test. If you select an UI component, for example a button, you can see on the table on the right its bounds!

Answer (score 0):

In developer options you can find Pointer locations in many devices. By the way X=0, Y=0 is top left corner and orientation doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android Settings->Developer Options and check Pointer location.

If you dont have Developer Options, go to Settings->About and tap 7 times on "build number" to enable it.